# Swift: testing against optional value in switch case

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, option-type

In Swift, how can I write a case in a switch statement that tests the value being switched against the contents of an *optional*, skipping over the case if the optional contains `nil`?

Here's how I imagine this might look:

```
let someValue = 5
let someOptional: Int? = nil

switch someValue {
case someOptional:
    // someOptional is non-nil, and someValue equals the unwrapped contents of someOptional
default:
    // either, someOptional is nil, or someOptional is non-nil but someValue does not equal the unwrapped contents of someOptional
}
```

If I just write it exactly like this, the compiler complains that `someOptional` is not unwrapped, but if I explicitly unwrap it by adding `!` to the end, I of course get a runtime error any time `someOptional` contains `nil`. Adding `?` instead of `!` would make some sense to me (in the spirit of optional chaining, I suppose), but doesn't make the compiler error go away (i.e. doesn't actually unwrap the optional).

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Optional is just a `enum` like this:

```
enum Optional<T> : Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case none
    case some(T)

    // ...
}
```

So you can match them as usual ["Associated Values"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_225) matching patterns:

```
let someValue = 5
let someOptional: Int? = nil

switch someOptional {
case .some(someValue):
    println("the value is \(someValue)")
case .some(let val):
    println("the value is \(val)")
default:
    println("nil")
}
```

If you want match from `someValue`, using [guard expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-XID_1063):

```
switch someValue {
case let val where val == someOptional:
    println(someValue)
default:
    break
}
```

**And for Swift > 2.0**

```
switch someValue {
case let val where val == someOptional:
    print("matched")
default:
    print("didn't match; default")        
}
```

Answer (score 67):

As of Xcode 7, *“a new `x?` pattern can be used to pattern match against optionals as a synonym for `.some(x)`”.* This means that in Swift 2 and later the following variation of [rintaro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941529/swift-testing-against-optional-value-in-switch-case/41355141#26941591) will work as well:

```swift
let knownValue = 5

switch someOptional {
case knownValue?:
    // Contents of someOptional are knownValue, defined above.
case let otherValue?:
    // Contents of someOptional are *any* non-nil value not already tested for.
    // Unwrapped contents are assigned to otherValue for use inside this case.
default:
    // someOptional is nil.
}
```

Comment: The question is about matching a non-optional value against an optional, this answer is the other way around.

Comment: True, however this answer was originally written by the OP as an update to the question so to him it was irrefutably a viable solution; I just moved it to a community wiki answer.  Perhaps @GeorgeWS can clarify as to why switching the switch & case args works for his use-case?

Comment: I'm a bit lost. what's the difference between your first two cases? `someValue?` is some other defined value, but `case let val?` is just the safe unwrapped version of `someOptional`?!

Comment: @Honey It's not a real-world code example; it's simply a variation on rintaro's answer.  So go ask him/her that question— my answer is functionally equivalent to the code in his/hers.  If you were to ask rintaro though, I believe the answer would be 1. it mirrors what's in the linked Apple docs; 2. it only demonstrates the syntax; it does not accomplish a distinct calculation or business logic goal.

Comment: @Honey Also, rintaro's answer was originally written for Swift 1.x and updated for Swift 2.  It's possible that the version without `let` no longer compiles.  I can't remember right now why that would've worked back in the day.

Comment: @Honey I think you're exactly right about the first two cases—the difference is that `someValue` was presumed to be a specific, known value we were checking for, whereas `val` was just *any* other non-optional value that `someOptional` might contain. I updated the code sample to make this more clear (renamed `someValue` → `knownValue` and `val` → `otherValue`, showed `knownValue` being assigned before the `switch`, and added more precise comments). Thanks for pointing out the confusing-ness of this—*totally* see why it was confusing, looking back at it a year+ later! 

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson The short answer to why this worked for me is… I don't remember. ‍♂️ 

Longer answer, looking back—I think switching the `switch` and `case`s worked here for me because I was able to find out what I wanted to know with either method of constructing the `switch` statement. Looking at the original question, I wanted to know if…

    `// someOptional is non-nil, and someValue equals the unwrapped contents of someOptional`

…which is true both in the first case of my imagined-switch in the question, and in the analogous second case here (`case let otherValue?`).

Answer (score 17):

In **Swift 4** you can use **Optional** of Apple to wrappe optional

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Example

```
enum MyEnum {
    case normal
    case cool
}
```

**some**

```
let myOptional: MyEnum? = MyEnum.normal

switch smyOptional {
    case .some(.normal): 
    // Found .normal enum
    break

    case .none: 
    break
    
    default:
    break
}
```

**none**

```
let myOptional: MyEnum? = nil

switch smyOptional {
    case .some(.normal): 
    break

    case .none: 
    // Found nil
    break
    
    default:
    break
}
```

**default**

```
let myOptional: MyEnum? = MyEnum.cool

switch smyOptional {
    case .some(.normal): 
    break

    case .none: 
    break
    
    default:
    // Found .Cool enum
    break
}
```

**Enum with value**

```
enum MyEnum {
    case normal(myValue: String)
    case cool
}
```

**some value**

```
let myOptional: MyEnum? = MyEnum.normal("BlaBla")

switch smyOptional {
case .some(.normal(let myValue)) where myValue == "BlaBla":
    // Here because where find in my myValue "BlaBla"
    break
    
// Example for get value
case .some(.normal(let myValue)):
    break
    
// Example for just know if is normal case enum
case .some(.normal):
    break
    
case .none:
    break
    
default:
    
    break
}
```

Comment: You mention `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` but then that is not actually used in the enum declarations etc. What is that?

Comment: @pkamb I removed, only Optional

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly mention all cases along with `nil` as an additional case to handle the optional:

```
switch optionalEnumValue {
case .caseOne:
    break
case .caseTwo:
    break
case .caseN:
    break
case nil:
    break
}
```

Comment: Feels like the cleanest answer to me.