# Use enum swift issue

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have enum:

```
enum VAXSettingsCells : Int
  {
    case SwitchModeCell = 0
    case SwitcherCell = 1
    case NewProgramCell = 2
    case CreatedProgramCell = 3
  }
```

which I use in my `UITableView` delegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
    let cellID = VAXSettingsCells(rawValue: indexPath.row)

    switch cellID {
    case .SwitchModeCell:
      let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(VAXSettingsSwitchModeCell.reusableCellIdentifier()) as! VAXSettingsSwitchModeCell
      cell.delegate = self
      return cell
```

But I get some error:

```
Enum case 'SwitchModeCell' not found in type 'VAXSettingsViewController.VAXSettingsCells?'
```

How to get rid of this error? Actually I can use raw values to get int and it will work but I want to use enum data instead as I don't want to use default case of switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to unwrap the VAXSettingsCells return optional value.

**If you define an enumeration with a raw-value type, the enumeration automatically receives an initializer that takes a value of the raw value’s type (as a parameter called rawValue) and returns either an enumeration case or nil**

```
if let cellID = VAXSettingsCells(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
switch cellID {

case .SwitchModeCell:
  // do whatever you want to do here
default: break

}

}
```

and In the example above, VAXSettingsCells has an implicit raw value of 0 for SwitchModeCell, and so on. so you don't need to give it explicitly. simply use

```
enum VAXSettingsCells : Int
{
 case SwitchModeCell
 case SwitcherCell
 case NewProgramCell
 case CreatedProgramCell
}
```

You access the raw value of an enumeration case with its rawValue property.

Comment: In this case using `!` after the enum initialization is probably a better solution because there is no way you can recover from an unknown cell.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, your `cellID` is of type `VAXSettingsCells?`, it's Optional and you cannot use it directly in switch-case statement.

Optional binding (if-let) would be a preferred solution, but you have another option. Use postfix `?` notation.

You can write your switch statement as:

```
    let cellID = VAXSettingsCells(rawValue: indexPath.row)

    switch cellID {
    case .SwitchModeCell?:
        let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(VAXSettingsSwitchModeCell.reusableCellIdentifier()) as! VAXSettingsSwitchModeCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    //...
```

Remember postfix `?` notation `case value?:` is just a shorthand of `case .Some(value):`. You'd better see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26941529/6541007).