# How to unwrapping an optional while pattern matching in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching, option-type

There are two `UIAlertView` variables but only one is optional. Let's say

```
lazy var a: UIAlertView = {

    return UIAlertView() // Which is not important here
}()

var b: UIAlertView?
```

and the delegate method

```
func alertView(alertView: SPAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

    switch (alertView, buttonIndex) {

    case (a, 0): // Do something
    case (a, 1): // Do something 
    case (b, 1): // <== Want to do something here but, b is optional.
    default: break
    }
}
```

How to unwrap `b` while pattern matching?

NB: The questions is about the `Swift language` not about the `UIAlertView`.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941529/swift-testing-against-optional-value-in-switch-case.

Comment: @MartinR No, my question is exactly the opposite of the question what you mentioned.

Comment: I don't think so. That *question* is how to match the non-optional `someValue` against the optional `someOptional` and that is exactly what you are asking. The first suggestion in the accepted answer does it the other way around, but the second suggestion `case let val where val == someOptional:` would work in your case as well (and is similar to what Callam suggested below).

Comment: @MartinR OK, then can you please combine `case let val where val == someOptional:`with @Callam's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a where clause to check if alertView is equal to `b`.

```
case (_, 1) where alertView == b:
```

To ensure `alertView` unwrapped in not nil, just replace the underscore with `.some`.

```
case (.Some, 1) where alertView == b:
```

Or similarly you could let the unwrapped alertView, but this is essentially the same as the above.

```
case (let .Some(_alertView), 1) where _alertView == b:
```

Comment: It works, but it is not satisfying me. There for let me wait for a while and make it as a right answer. Until then a up vote. Thanks.

Comment: @Goppinath thanks for the upvote. What is bothering you exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this (using `?` in the case) 
You'll need to add self.b to the tuple that you are switching on:

```
func alertView(alertView: SPAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    switch (b, alertView, buttonIndex) {
    case (_, a, 0), (_,a,1): // Do something
    case (b?, a, 1): //  <==  b is not optional here (only matches case .Some = b and binds to local variable `b`
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work. May be it is because I am still using Swift 2.2?

Comment: Updated, let me know if that doesn't compile